# Nothing Found for Index Php Error

Tags: iis

I moved my word press blog from Apache to IIS 7 shared hosting. my database connection is fine. I can access the admin module but I get an empty index.php with "Nothing Found for Index Php Error" in the title bar. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by going to *Settings>Permalinks*, now click on the default radio button and click save. You probably used .htaccess to enable pretty permalinks, IIS doesn't use an .htaccess file.

If the default structure fixed the problems you are having, but you want the old permalink structure, click this link to the WP-Codex page explaining how:
[Link to Codex Page *(about half way down)*.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: Thanks .. Jeremy .. It worked except having the old permalink  part. I am not able to use permalink. Even though it is IIS 7 ,may be because of "URL Rewrite " module is not there.

Comment: I'm not an IIS Expert, but I've dealt with enough to know I prefer Linux 100%. I would never switch on purpose. If you need help installing the rewrite module, post your progress and problem, maybe I can help.