# Wordpress, IIS7, SQL Server 2008, not showing posts (displays 'Nothing Found...') and only shows counts in admin - how to fix?

Tags: iis, mssql

I recently installed WordPress on IIS 7 and wired it up to SQL Server 2008R2.  The installation went fine.

Right off the bat, I can see on post is present (just in the count) but none are listed; I added a few posts.

In the admin menu, under posts, I see that there are six published posts "Published (6)".  However the list below this is empty.  Also trying to view these on the site, by selecting the category returns

> **Nothing Found**
>
> Apologies, but no results were found for the requested
>   archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.

I have re-installed the database, overwrote the PHP/SQL files and re-installed WP.  Problem persists.

I tried the Settings/Permalinks suggestions [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/nothing-found-for-index-php-error) and.  No change.

The suggestions [here](http://www.squidoo.com/wordpress-not-found-error-fix) relate to not being able to write to the .htaccess file.  Not an issue for me, and I am not seeing the error of not being able to save.  (To verify, I saved, exited, navigated to the same Permalinks page and my settings were saved).

I even set the Permalinks to to default and removed the Web.config rewrite rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
     </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

No change. (Added them back in).

I set SAVEQUERIES=TRUE in wp-config.php and I can see the contents of some of the posts in the log file.

> ie. Hi there! I'm a bike messenger by day, aspiring actor by night,
>   and this is my blog. I live in Los Angeles, have a great dog named
>   Jack...

Enabled the php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll extension and disabled phpsqlsrv.dll

I have seen other posts that refer to changing some security settings as the system may be detecting a potential SQL injection attack.  However those posts are related to an Apache-related installation, and cannot locate any references in my version.

I retried this with WP 3.21 - same issue.

I can click on the month link (March) then see that the post count beside Uncategorized.  Once I click on the link, I see the Nothing Found message again.

Retried with 3.31, and noticed the following in Windows/Temp/php53_errors.log:

> [07-Mar-2012 21:00:51 UTC] WordPress database error 42000 :
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax
>   near 'wp_users'. for query SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ''wp_users'' made by
>   display_setup_form, pdo_wpdb->query, pdo_wpdb->_post_query,
>   pdo_wpdb->print_error

Upon installation, and tracked it down to wp-content\mu-plugins\wp-db-abstraction\translations\sqlsrv\translations.php.

In this case, adding extra single quotes around the table name was causing the error, so I commented out the line:

```
    // SHOW TABLES
    if ( strtolower($query) === 'show tables;' ) {
        $query = str_ireplace('show tables',"select name from SYSOBJECTS where TYPE = 'U' order by NAME",$query);
    }
    if ( stripos($query, 'show tables like ') === 0 ) {
        $end_pos = strlen($query);
        $param = substr($query, 17, $end_pos - 17);
        // quoted with double quotes instead of single?
        $param = trim($param, '"');
        if($param[0] !== "'") {
            //$param = "'$param'";          <----------- commented out
        }
        $query = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ' . $param;
    }
```

Now, the SQL statement reads

> SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE
>   'wp_users'

instead of

> SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE
>   ''wp_users''

Retried the installation - problem persists, but this time no SQL error message.

**-- Update --**

Forgot to mention that I am using this with the [WP DB Abstraction](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-database-abstraction/) (implied by ...

> wp-content\mu-plugins\wp-db-abstraction\translations\sqlsrv\translations.php

... above.   Is there another way to get this to work with SQL Server?

Comment: Is this just the stock WordPress? Are you running this with it: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-database-abstraction/

Comment: @Kev - yes, with db abstraction. Still can't get around this issue.

Comment: I also facing same issue. Did you also got same problems for the media library?

Comment: Interesting as I too am seeing the same results. I have even updated the SQL PHP drivers from 2.0 to 3.0 from our good friends at MS...
Ron

Comment: There are a few problems listed.  Surprisingly one is directly right from the database setup process, and I'm curious as to why there are no solutions/responses to this yet.  We have somewhat abandoned this effort as our requirements have changed, however I'm still looking forward to a solution for.  As I don't have the cycles to resolve, the starting point would be the sprocs that retrieve the data.  My suspicion is that the count sprocs are different than the data retrieval sprocs/functions.  Check for a common PHP module (and trace it back), as the same problem is seen on the admin side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. From my log file I can see its breaking on the query that returns the posts.

I managed to get this working by going to "wp-includes\query.php", and then removing the $limits variable from the query.

It seems that this is breaking on sql server.

Find this line:

$this->request = " SELECT $found_rows $distinct $fields FROM $wpdb->posts $join WHERE 1=1 $where $groupby $orderby $limits";

change to:

$this->request = " SELECT $found_rows $distinct $fields FROM $wpdb->posts $join WHERE 1=1 $where $groupby $orderby";

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: That’s probably the worst solution: Now you have to re-edit the files after each update. Use a filter on `'query'` instead.

Comment: You might be right, but my answer is to get the site working. There are a few other things I found that can cause problems too, so still working on these myself.

Comment: @edwardl - Can you share what other things are causing issues and provide the solutions for them?  What was the value of $limits in the first query when you ran it?  Can you post the actual queries?

Comment: @toscho - I found an error in the setup code that, unless it's changed, will require a code change after each update.  See my comments above.  So this being a bug would warrant that, don't you think?  I'm removing the -1.

Comment: @ElHaix If it is a bug in WordPress [open a Trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/newticket). If it is a plugin bug, fix the plugin and contact its author. Anyway, I would rather filter the SQL request on the `'query'` hook than changing the core files.

Comment: Low and behold, I had to do another WordPress (3.5) install with IIS/SQL Server, and this issue came up.  Removing $limits from the query works just fine.  toscho - what do you mean by use a filter on 'query' instead?

Comment: I will not recommend this as it require editing of wordpress core files which is a bad practice. Check here for better approach: http://www.wptricks24.com/post-listing-not-showing-wordpress-admin-iis-sql-server-database